# ordenar left join segun su id desc

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta consulta mysql:

```
"SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('<option value=\"',pl.id_lote,'\">',DATE(pl.fecha),'  |  ',pl.unidades,' uni. |  S/ ',pl.precio_costo,'</option>' SEPARATOR '') AS options,c.canal
from productos_lotes pl
left join canales c on c.id_canal = pl.id_canal
where pl.id_producto = "123"
group by pl.id_canal
ORDER BY pl.id_lote desc
"
```

pero esto me muestra los registros en orden de registrados asc mas no en el orden desc quisiera saber en que estoy fallando porfavor.

Comment: ¿Qué es “registrados”?

Comment: el orden en que se hizo el insert

Answer (score 0):

Solo te falta agregar **DESC**

```
"SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT('<option value=\"',pl.id_lote,'\">',DATE(pl.fecha),'  |  
',pl.unidades,' uni. |  S/ ',pl.precio_costo,'</option>' SEPARATOR '') AS 
options,c.canal
from productos_lotes pl
left join canales c on c.id_canal = pl.id_canal
where pl.id_producto = "123"
group by pl.id_canal
ORDER BY DESC pl.id_lote desc"
```